# Binding lots of objects visibility in javascript. Managing the current state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm writing a website where the user would hit a button to start.
Depending on which button they push, a new section on the page will appear.
More buttons in this section - hit one of those buttons and one of a few sections will appear.

I have code which is starting to get really long and messy.

So I was looking for a cleaner/better way of managing what needs to be visible at any one time.

I want to avoid installing something like angular/react/knockout - because it seems like a lot of overhead for just 1 page on a large(ish) website.  So ideally just naked javascript or jquery.

But i'd also like to avoid pages and pages of javascript full of $('div1').show(); $('div2').hide();
etc
And it is becoming difficult to manage them all.

I've created a fiddle so hopefully you can see what I am trying to accomplish (it's only about 1/5 complete but already looking a mess):
https://jsfiddle.net/6w4mfndf/

But basically it's looking like this at the moment:

```
<div name="Group1">
  <input name="group1" type="radio" id="btn1" />
  <span>1</span>           

  <input name="group1" type="radio" id="btn2" />
  <span>2</span> 
<div>

<div name="group2">
<div id="div_btn1" style="display:none">
      <input name="group2" type="radio" id="btn1_1" />
      <span>1_1</span>

      <input name="group2" type="radio" id="btn1_2" />
      <span>1_1</span>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(function () {
        $('#btn1').change(function() {

            if ($('#btn1').is(':checked')) {
                $('#div_btn1').show();
                $('#div_btn1_1').hide();
            }
        });
</script>
```

I am working with MVC if there is any kind of way that can be used to help model the data out.  (Unlikely I'd guess, but just throwing it out there).

Any solutions I am missing?

Comment: Is it one section to be displayed per button (in which case you can relate a `data` attribute with the button with the associated `<div>` so there is only one simple script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try to have a class that is shared by all the buttons which triggers the js and a data attribute that informs the js as to which div of content to show?

Something along these lines for example:

```
<div class="content-block" id="content1">
Content 1
</div>

<div class="content-block" id="content2">
    Content 2
</div>

<button class="content-button" data-content-block="content1" value="content 1"></button>

<button class="content-button" data-content-block="content2" value="content 2"></button>

<script>
$(function () {

    $(".content-block").hide();

   $(".content-button").click(function() {

         $(".content-block").hide();

        var contentBlock = $(this).attr("data-content-block");

        $("#" + contentBlock).show();
   });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks that has probably saved me a few hundred lines of redundant javascript. So much easier to keep track of too.

Comment: @jb. No worries bud, glad it helped!